# How do I run a PostgreSQL container using docker-compose with startup files that depends on .env values, then running node-pg-migrate?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, node-pg-migrate

I want the following flow.

- PostgreSQL runs startup script with the values from .env file
- PostgreSQL runs successfully
- App runs successfully
- Run migration commands. I have already created the scripts for migration commands. This is done using `node-pg-migrate` module, and I simply need to run `npm run migrate up` after the app runs successfully.

I have the following startup scripts for my PostgreSQL.

First file (`./initdb.d/001_create_database.sql`)

```
CREATE DATABASE ${PGDATABASE};
```

Second file (`./initdb.d/002_create_user.sql`)

```
CREATE USER ${PGUSER} WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '${PGPASSWORD}';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE ${PGDATABASE} TO ${PGUSER};
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public to ${PGUSER};
```

I have the following `.env` file.

```
#db config
PGUSER={something}
PGHOST={something}
PGPASSWORD={something}
PGDATABASE={something}
PGPORT={something}
```

I have the following `Dockerfile` for my Node.js app.

```
FROM node:14
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gettext-base
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN git clone https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it.git
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start-dev" ]
```

Then, I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
    restart: on-failure
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "${PGPORT}:${PGPORT}"
    volumes:
      - "./initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
      - musicapidata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: root
      POSTGRES_USER: root
  redis:
    ...
  rabbitmq:
    ...
  migration:
    build:
      context: .
    command:
      [
        "./wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh",
        "postgres:5432",
        "--",
        "npm",
        "run",
        "migrate",
        "up"
      ]
    links:
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
volumes:
  musicapidata:
```

I have tried using `envsubst` in my `Dockerfile`, but it doesn't work as the PostgreSQL service will copy the SQL script files with the placeholder values. Could someone guide me on how to do this?

**EDIT**

I have tried the following as well. I think I'm close.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - pgversion=13
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "${PGPORT}:${PGPORT}"
    volumes:
      - "./initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
      - musicapidata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: root
      POSTGRES_USER: root
```

`Dockerfile-postgres`

```
ARG pgversion
FROM postgres:$pgversion

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gettext-base
COPY initdb.d /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
WORKDIR /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
COPY .env ./

RUN envsubst < ./001_create_database.sql
RUN envsubst < ./002_create_user.sql
```

Unfortunately, it is copying the .env just right, but it si not running the `envsubst` yet.

Comment: The [`postgres` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) has standard environment variables to create a user and a database; how are your scripts different from what _e.g._ `POSTGRES_DB` creates automatically?

Comment: @DavidMaze Because I don't want my env variables to be visible in the `docker-compose.yml` file (which I will commit to Github) so I want it to be in an `.env` file.

Comment: That's not a problem, you can use a Compose [`env_file:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) directive to inject per-container environment variables from an external file.  Trying to `RUN envsubst` is arguably worse because it will persist the credentials in the image in clear text.

Comment: @DavidMaze I see. Do you have a link (doc/reading article) that mentions how I can use `env_file` from Compose to inject per-container environment variables, and then use it to create a database and a user with the privileges mentioned in the question?

Comment: @DavidMaze Hey, I got it to work. Turns out I just need to use the same environment variable name in the `.env` file. However, when I check the container's environment variables by printing out the env, it seems that all is visible in the container's environment. Is this normal?